# Can I restore GPG password from backup key?

Tags: gnupg

I've forgot my GPG password. But I have a backup of private key. Can I restore my password from backup file of secret key ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you've forgotten the passphrase on your GPG private key. Is your backup an unencrypted copy of the private key? If so, yes you can. If it's encrypted using the same passphrase as you've forgotten now, it won't help you.

Comment: @gertvdijk how can I know which key is used to encrypt it? I can remember that I did something like `gpg -ao myprivate.key --export-secret-keys <key>` to export secret key.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted my previous comment. There's a *passphrase* (as in, password) to encrypt a private key.